# VBA_Excel takes a date variable and pastes it inside a cell as a number

Tags: excel, vba, format, excel-2010, paste

Ok i have this small code

```
If Trim(apriori) <> "" Then
        With Sheets(yolk).Range("1:1")
            Set Rng = .Find(apriori, .Cells(.Cells.Count), xlValues, xlWhole, xlByRows, _
                            xlNext, False)
            yolk = yolk - 1
            'e = 1
            If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
                'Application.Goto Rng, True
                Rng.Offset(26, 0).Copy 'Worksheets("EXTRACTIONS").Range("B2").Offset(, e)
                some_date = Format(apriori, "dd/mmmm/yyyy") 'XX
                MsgBox some_date
                Worksheets("EXTRACTIONS").Range("B2").Offset(, e).Value = some_date 'XX
                Worksheets("EXTRACTIONS").Range("B3").Offset(, e).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues 'EDIT
                e = e + 1
                'activeCell kane offset ekei pou theloume
                'prwta offset theloume to address pou tha kanei to offset
                'timy = ActiveCell.Address
            Else
                MsgBox "Nothing found"
            End If
        End With
End If
```

The value `apriori` is a `date value` in US format and all i want is to convert it to the way dates look at calendars for example:

`12/31/2010 to 31/December/2010`

so i use

`format(apriori, "dd/mmmm/yyyy")`

and it does the job and i have the date as i want her to be in the `msgbox some_date`

**However once i try to paste** the value to a cell with

```
Worksheets("EXTRACTIONS").Range("B2").Offset(, e).Value = some_date
```

**The cell gets populated with numbers(!!!!) like 41,274 or 41,679.....(?)**

How can i correct this bug in my `VBA` code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change *number format* of your cell like this:

```
Dim some_date As Date
some_date = Now

With Worksheets("EXTRACTIONS").Range("B2").Offset(, e)
    .NumberFormat = "dd/mmmm/yyyy"
    .Value = some_date
End With
```

Comment: YEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAHHHHH LOVE YOU PAL!